# Is this CSS, obscuring text, really SEO friendly?

Tags: html, css, seo

Is this code, used on http://www.fleep.art.br/, SEO friendly? I don't believe Google is so easily tricked. The site has an h1 CSS class with `color: #fff` (the background is fff too) and `font-size: 1px;`.

```
h1.seo {
font-size: 1px;
color: #fff;
position: absolute;
right: 0;
}
```

HTML:

```
<h1 class='seo'>web design curitiba</h1>
<h1 class='seo'>web sites curitiba</h1>
<h1 class='seo'>design grafico curitiba</h1>
<h1 class='seo'>publicidade curitiba</h1>
```

And, above all my distrust, the site is well positioned in Google. And it seems that this h1 classes is ALL the content in the site, the rest is just pictures! So weird. Any thoughts about this?

Comment: i also did about a year ago and i think it worked, but its very very very not pretty

Comment: It's not a technique I would recommend using. Perhaps it works now, but it may get punished later.

Comment: As Brad said search engines are pretty complex. These days, though you can't just dock a site for something like that because it could be part of a javascript based style animation or something that reveals the text after load. However, not being an agent for search engines, I don't know if I can definitively say whether or not search engines care about what you do with the text. It might dock you just for doing it in this way to begin with.

Comment: Techniques to improve, understand and/or measure SEO is off topic

Comment: Google will never punish someone for Good UX, so if you are to implement it ensuring that a user can navigate to the anchor text, they would be kind to it. 

What I can say, for sure, is **bad SEO** is having 4 h1 tags. One h1 tag per page, anymore would mean only the first h1 would be recognised to be of any weight in the eyes of Search Engines.

Answer (score 2):

Search engines have long caught on to tactics like this.  It is certainly not SEO friendly.

If it's ranked well, it probably has a decent number of varied sites linking to it, among other reasons.  There are a ton of factors that go into a page rank, and position in search results.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to future-proof your site for search engines is to focus on your content and use valid HTML.

Tricks like these are a blacklist waiting to happen.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to optimize a site for search engines is to code them properly, get lots of people to link to it (making it seem more popular/relevant), and have quality content. Essentially, search engines like Google are going to reward good information architecture as they improve their algorithms.

For a good intro to how search engines rank sites: http://moz.com/beginners-guide-to-seo